# Supernova light flash propagating through universe

Tags: cosmology, supernova

Let the spherical light flash of a Supernove expand with c through the universe. Provided that the size of the unverse is limited, that sphere of light would inevitably reach a hypothesized end of the universe.
It is elementary knowledge that a spherical wave on the surface of a 3-dimensional sphere initially expands but after having passed the equator of that sphere would contract and finally reach the size of the initial flash, however on the opposed side of that sphere.
The question thus simply is if a Supernova flash would also contract to its initial size after having passed the universe?

Comment: A closed universe cannot have constant size. It has to be initially expanding then contracting. So it is not as simple as a light wave front moving around a sphere of constant radius. The light wave front would indeed start contracting as the universe started contracting and would end up with zero size when it hit the Big Crunch singularity, but then so would everything else.

Answer (score 0):

A finite universe with a positive cosmological constant is likely to be such that it continues to grow, but after a long while when all of the Omega terms are reduced by their power of **a** denominators, then the cosmological constant will continue to expand the universe size. However, the rate of expansion will decline towards a constant value. If the cosmological constant is zero or negative, then the expansion will stop and contraction will take place until temperature approaches infinity.

Answer (score -2):

That Supernova flash of light must contract to its initial size after having crossed the universe.